# Linq to entities query with nested query on the same table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct A.stock_value_site,
                A.BALANCE_QUANTITY,
                A.BALANCE_NOMINAL_VALUE, 
                A.BALANCE_INDEXED_VALUE,
                V.STOCK_VALUE_ORDER,
                U.BALANCE_QUANTITY  
FROM            svr A,   
                svt V,
                svu U
WHERE V.Code = 500 and  
      A.Id = U.ID (+) and
      A.Id = (SELECT    max(B.id) 
              FROM      svr B,
                        sts
              WHERE     A.stock_value_site = B.stock_value_site and 
                        B.Id = sts.ID(+) and
                        B.item = _item and 
                        B.date < _from_date and
                        B.Id IS NULL)
```

I tried to convert this query to Linq to entities:

```
var data = (from A in _context.svr
           join V in _context.svt on A.svtId equals V.Code
           join U in _context.svu on A.Id equals U.Id into groupA
           from gA in groupA.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where V.Code == _openBalanceRecordId &&
                 A.Id == (from B in _context.svr
                          join st in _context.sts on B.Id equals st.Id into groupB
                          from gB in groupB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where A.svsId == B.svsId &&
                                B.ItemId == _item &&
                                B.Date < _startDate.Date
                          select B.Id).Max()
           select new
           {
               A.stock_value_site,
               A.BALANCE_QUANTITY,
               A.BALANCE_NOMINAL_VALUE, 
               A.BALANCE_INDEXED_VALUE,
               V.STOCK_VALUE_ORDER,
               gA == null ? 0 : gA.BALANCE_QUANTITY
           }).Distinct().ToList();
```

When I run the SQL query in oracle I get 33 records back. But when I run it using Linq to entities I don't get any record.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What tables to `_item` and `_from_date`? Also `B.Id = sts.ID and ... B.Id IS NULL` -- both of these cannot ever be true because if `B.ID` is `null` it cannot equal `sts.ID`,

Comment: _item, _from_aate, _startDate are all variables not tables.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, my mistake.. will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are still some issues with you're original query, if I understand what you're trying to do, this should work better:

```
var results = 
    (from a in _context.svr
     from v in _context.svt.Where(t => t.Code == 500)
     join u in _context.svu on u.Id equals a.Id into gU
     from x in gU.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where a.Id == 
         (from b in _context.svr
          join s in _context.sts on b.Id equals s.Id
          where b.item = _item
          and b.date < _from_date
          and b.svsId == a.svsId
          select b.Id).Max()
     select new
     {
         a.stock_value_site,
         a.BALANCE_QUANTITY,
         a.BALANCE_NOMINAL_VALUE, 
         a.BALANCE_INDEXED_VALUE,
         v.STOCK_VALUE_ORDER,
         x == null ? 0 : x.BALANCE_QUANTITY
     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Or possibly this:

```
var results = 
    (from a in _context.svr
     from v in _context.svt.Where(t => t.Code == 500)
     join u in _context.svu on u.Id equals a.Id into gU
     from x in gU.DefaultIfEmpty()
     let subQuery = 
         (from b in _context.svr
          join s in _context.sts on b.Id equals s.Id
          where b.item = _item
          and b.date < _from_date
          select new { b.Id, b.svsId })
     join y in subQuery on a.svsId equals y.svsId into gY
     where a.Id = y.Max(b => b.Id)
     select new
     {
         a.stock_value_site,
         a.BALANCE_QUANTITY,
         a.BALANCE_NOMINAL_VALUE, 
         a.BALANCE_INDEXED_VALUE,
         v.STOCK_VALUE_ORDER,
         x == null ? 0 : x.BALANCE_QUANTITY
     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I tries the first query you suggested and it works like a charm. Thank you very much for that. Could you shed some light on the nested query presented in the where clause? I also noticed that you omiited the 'st' table (dbset) from the query why?

Comment: @Shpongle Oops! that's actually a typo. Your sql query had an inner join (kinda) but your Linq had a left join. I just wrote my query to try to match your original sql. Actually, if you're doing a left join, but not selecting anything from `st` you can just drop the join on `sts`.